# Where can I find detailed data about crimes in Italy?

Tags: crime, italy

Where can I find detailed data about crimes committed in Italy? The data set should contain at least the following variables:

```
Type of crime:
Year:
Municipality: 
Criminal:
Victim:
Ethnicity of criminal:
Nationality of criminal:
Age of criminal:
```

Ps I guess it may not be possible have all these pieces of information in the same data set. It would be ok to point me to two different data sets (one with crimes data and another with census data). Then I think I should be able to create the tables I need by using the right SQL joins.

Comment: See also https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41862/are-a-third-of-the-crimes-in-italy-committed-by-migrants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to look at this link:
https://www.istat.it/en/justice-and-security?data-and-indicators

under the "Data And Microdata" tab.

Here you can find a lot of information that may fit what you're looking for.

I don't know if you're italian but ISTAT is the italian institute for statistics.

Hope you can find this useful!

Comment: This looks nice, but it's not uber- friendly to navigate, in order to get the info I'm looking for. I'll try poking at it a bit, and maybe ask another answer if I need help finding the info I need.